# How to visualize ludwig library models learning curves programatically?

Tags: python, machine-learning, ludwig

I am using Uber's [ludwig](https://github.com/uber/ludwig) library to train neural network models. I want to programatically (via python code, using the [documentation's example](https://github.com/uber/ludwig/blob/master/mkdocs/docs/api/visualization.md#learning_curves)) visualize the learning curves of my models to analyze their performance using the following code:

```
import ludwig
ludwig.visualize.learning_curves(
  [train_stats],
  TARGET,
  model_names=None,
  output_directory=None,
  file_format='pdf'
)
```

However, I am obtaining the following error when running the code:

```
AttributeError: module 'ludwig' has no attribute 'visualize'
```

I know that I can generate the visualization via command line. However, I need to do it programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run the same code without changing it. I just updated the version of ludwig but I am not sure if that was the solution to my problem. I kept using this piece of code and it worked:

```
import ludwig
ludwig.visualize.learning_curves(
  [train_stats],
  TARGET,
  model_names=None,
  output_directory=None,
  file_format='pdf'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like that.

```
from ludwig import visualize
visualize.learning_curves(
  [train_stats],
  TARGET,
  model_names=None,
  output_directory=None,
  file_format='pdf'
)
```